# I want to send live data from html to action-script 3 based on some event generated from html via the swf file

Tags: html, actionscript

I am playing a flash video from swf file in html. Upon pause event from html, i need to send the data from html to actionscript in flash professional

Comment: Can you post a sample code. It's very hard to post an answer without knowing the specifics

Comment: Research into AS3 [**External Interface**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=R7RYXJiOCM6SsAejh6uYBw&q=as3+ExternalInterface) API. That will allow you to send data between Flash and JavaScript. I don't know what your _"live data"_ means (talking about text? numbers? pictures? sounds?). That's why we ask for code. Do what you can and then show us what or how you've tried to send to Flash, then we can help you.